# Show that $r^n\rightarrow 0$ if $|r|<1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $r\in \mathbb{C}$, $|r|<1$. Show that $r^n\rightarrow 0$.

For that we have to show that $r^n$ is decreasing and bounded, right?

Let $a_n:=r^n$.

Then we have that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{r^{n+1}}{r^n}=r\leq |r|<1$ and so the sequence is decreasing.

Since $|r|<1$ we get that $-1<r<1\Rightarrow (-1)^n<r^n<1^n \Rightarrow (-1)^n<r^n<1$ and so the sequence is bounded.

So we know that the sequence converges to a limit $L$.

We have that $r^{n+1}=r\cdot r^n$. Since $r^n\rightarrow L$ we also have that $r^{n+1}\rightarrow L$ and so we get for $n\rightarrow \infty$ that $L=r\cdot L\Rightarrow L\cdot (r-1)=0$ and since $|r|<1$ and so $r\neq 1$ it follows that $L=0$.

Is everything correct?

Comment: "Being decreasing and bounded implies convergence" only happens for real numbers. There's no (usual) definition of "decreasing" in $\Bbb C$... For your question, in complex numbers "tends to zero" means exactly "the modulus tends to zero". That's it. So you only need to show $|r^n|$ tends to zero.

Comment: **Alternative:** For $r\not=0$, write $|r|=\frac{1}{1+h}$ for some $h>0$, and then $$|r|^n=\frac{1}{(1+h)^n}$$$$=\frac{1}{1+\binom{n}{1}h+\binom{n}{2}h^2+...+h^n}$$$$\leq \frac{1}{1+nh}\to 0\text{ as }n\to \infty.$$

Comment: $(-1)^2 < r < 1^2$? Also, in general, you can't compare complex numbers. However, you can easily modify your proof so it would work.

Comment: So having shown that $|r|^n\rightarrow 0$ is equivalent to $r^n\rightarrow 0$ ? @SumantaDas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. Even assuming that $r\in\Bbb R$, you did not prove correctly that the sequence is decreasing, and you could not have possibly have done so, since, if $-1<r<0$, the sequence is *not* decreasing (nor increasing, for that matter).

Besides, you don't *have* to prove that the sequence is bounded and decreasing.

Comment: Ah so since $r\in \mathbb{C}$ and not just $r\in \mathbb{R}$ we cannot just shown that the sequence is bounded and decreasing?

Comment: Even if $r\in\Bbb R$, the sequence might not be decreasing.

Comment: Ahh ok! What should we do in this case to show the convergence?

Comment: Your approach actually show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|r|^n=0$, which is the same thing as asserting that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|r^n|=0$. But asserting that a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $0$ is the same thing as asserting that the sequence $(|a_n|)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $0$, since both assertions mean that$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists N\in\Bbb N):n\geqslant N\implies|a_n|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: For $|r|=0$ we have that $r=0$ and so $r^n\rightarrow 0$, right?  
Let $a_n:=|r|^n$ with $|r|\neq 0$. Then we have that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{|r|^{n+1}}{|r|^n}=|r|<1$ and so $a_n$ is decreasing. 
Since $0\leq |r|<1$, $a_n$ is bounded.  
So $a_n$ converges to a limit $L$. 
We have that $|r|^{n+1}=|r|\cdot |r|^n$. Since $|r|^n\rightarrow L$ it is also $|r|^{n+1}\rightarrow L$ and so we get for $n\rightarrow \infty$ that $L=|r|\cdot L\Rightarrow L\cdot (|r|-1)=0$ and since $|r|<1$ it follows that $L=0$. 
So $|r|^n\rightarrow 0$ which is equivalent to $|r^n|\rightarrow 0$. Is all right?

Comment: Yes, all of that is correct.

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

As for any complex number $$|r^n-0|=||r|^n-0|$$ it suffices to show that the property holds in the reals.

Let $s:=|r|>0$. Now for any $\epsilon>0$, $|s^n-0|<\epsilon$ if $n\ge\log_s\epsilon$, and the latter expression is always defined. (Needless to say, $s=0$ also works.)

Answer (score 1):

So $|z^n - 0| = |z^n| = |z|^n \rightarrow 0$, which is the definition of $z^n \rightarrow 0$.